# My personal way to try to show that if $L$ is the set of limits points of $A\subset\Bbb R$ then $L$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Im trying to make the proof on this way: I can define the set of limits points of $A$ as $$L=\{l:(a_n)\to l, a_n\in A\}$$

The hypothesis is that $L$ is closed, i.e. $\forall (l_n)\to m\implies m\in L$. Then I want to show that if

$$\forall l_n\in L: (l_n)\to m\implies\exists a_n\in A :(a_n)\to m$$

i.e. every limit point of $L$ belongs to $L$ and because is a limit point it must exist some sequence of points of $A$ that converges to it.

Then I started thinking that I can pick a set of $a_n$ from every sequence that converges to some point of the sequence $(l_n)$ close enough to make a convergent sequence to $m$ i.e. taking $|a_k-l_k|<\varepsilon : \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(l_n)=m$ but because $\varepsilon>0$ the unique way to assure that these quantities design a convergent sequence is making them convergent to zero.

If I choose $\{\varepsilon>0\}:(\varepsilon_k)\to 0$ then I think the proof is done because I will had that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(l_n+\varepsilon_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(l_n)+\lim_{n\to\infty}(\varepsilon_n)=m+0=m$$

My question: this is something wrong in this proof or lack of something? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. You need to be a little bit careful about what indices you are using. But you can take $\epsilon_n = 1/n$ for example. Then for each $n$ there is some sequence $(a_k)\subset A$, which converges to $l_n$. Hence for each $n$ there is an index $K(n)$ such that $|a_{K(n)}- l_n| < 1/n$.

Define a sequence $(b_n)\subset A$ by $b_n = a_{K(n)}$. Then given an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, we can let $N$ be large enough so that $1/N < \epsilon$; then we have
     $$|b_n - m| \leq |b_n - l_n| + |l_n - m| < \frac{1}{n} + \epsilon < 2\epsilon$$
for all $n > N$. In other words, $b_n \to m$. This is essentially what you wrote down.

Comment: Yes, formalizing through multiple index is a bit annoying, thank you to show me the way to formalize it.

Comment: You are welcome. It is easy to get lost in reindexing subsequences and such. If you want to clean things up, you can probably just write $K$ instead of $K(n)$; I just wrote it that way to reinforce that this index $K$ depends on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the right idea but it needs to be formalized.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

By definition of $L$, for all $n$ we can find* $a_n \in A$ such that $|l_n - a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

$(a_n)$ then defines a sequence in $A$.

Because $\lim(l_n) = m$, there is $N$ such that for $n \geq N$, $|l_n - m| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Then for  $n \geq N$, we get $|a_n - m| = |a_n - l_n + l_n - m|\leq |a_n - l_n| + |l_n - m| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$

Hence $ \lim(a_n) = m $ so $L$ is closed.

*For each $n$, there is a sequence of elements in $A$ which converges to $l_n$. So there must be an element $a_n$ in this sequence such that $|a_n - l_n| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Comment: Yes, I see... this way is more easy to do, taking the Cauchy sequence definition for convergence more a triangle inequality then is unnecessary define a sequence of $\varepsilon$ that converges to zero. I appreciate the answer to show me something better but I will put the validation on the other answer because I think it answer more precisely what I wanted.